# CSS Layout nested div's weird behavior

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout

I have a webpage im trying to layout and it current looks like this.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4TOb.jpg

I want the purple box to be inline w/ the pink box in the yellow box, which is in the green box. When i change the display field in css to inline-block for the two the whole green box moves down to bottom of grey box w/ height = to yellow box. Why is this happening?

CSS

```
div.localPlayer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  left:0;
  height: 300px;
  background: rgb(181, 181, 181);
  text-align:center;
}

div.coinStatus {
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color:yellow;
}

div.coinInfo {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: purple;
  display: block;
}

div.coin {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: pink;
  display: block;
  background-image: url('../images/6.png');
}

div.status {
  postion: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 280px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  background-size: cover;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: green;
}

div.card {
  width: 180px;
  height: 280px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  background-size: cover;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

div.card.1 {
  background-image: url('../images/1.png');
}
div.card.2 {
  background-image: url('../images/2.png');
}
div.card.3 {
  background-image: url('../images/3.png');
}
div.card.4 {
  background-image: url('../images/4.png');
}
div.card.5 {
  background-image: url('../images/5.png');
}
```

HTML

```
<html>
   <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/coup.css">
      <script src="js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/file.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div> Image </div>
      <div id="this" class="localPlayer">
         <div id="card1" class="card 1"></div>
         <div id="card2" class="card 2"></div>
         <div id="status" class="status">
            <div id="coinStatus" class="coinStatus">
               <div class="coin"></div>
               <div id="numberOfCoins" class="coinInfo"></div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please, remove unnecessary CSS rules and check each CSS rule

Comment: Try `vertical-align: top` on `div.status` : http://jsbin.com/popajequqo/1/edit?html,css

Answer (score 0):

`inline-block` elements default alignment is `vertical-align:bottom`. So that it is going down to bottom. Apply `vertical-align:top` for your inline block elements. Hopefully it will fix the issue.

```
 div.status {
 postion: relative;
 width: 400px;
 height: 280px;
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 10px;
 background-size: cover;
 border-radius: 10px;
 background: green;
 vertical-align:top;
 }

 div.card {
  width: 180px;
  height: 280px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  background-size: cover;
  border-radius: 10px;
 vertical-align:top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this " adding float: left might fix this

```css
div.localPlayer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  left:0;
  height: 300px;
  background: rgb(181, 181, 181);
  text-align:center;
}

div.coinStatus {
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  display: block;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color:yellow;
}

div.coinInfo {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: purple;
  display: block;
  float:left;
}

div.coin {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: pink;
  display: block;
  float:left;
}

div.status {
  postion: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 280px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  background-size: cover;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: green;
  vertical-align:top;
}

div.card {
  width: 180px;
  height: 280px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  background-size: cover;
  border-radius: 10px;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```